# Count in Spring Data JPQL join query throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a query using JPQL in the annotation @Query in Spring Data which looks like below

```
@Query(value = "select distinct a from EntityA as a left join fetch a.listEntityB as b where ...")
  public List<EntityA > find....(@Param("") String value, Pageable pageable);
```

Now I need to know the total number of records of the query. As Pageable is giving me partial list, I am writing another count query without the Pageable. My count query looks like below:

```
@Query(value = "select count(distinct a) from EntityA as a left join fetch a.listEntityB as b where ...) 
  public long count...(@Param("") String value);
```

However, I am getting "IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query" error from this query to count the records. When I change the count query to "select count(distinct a) from EntityA" , it works fine. I am not sure what is the problem when I use the join. I did not get any helpful documents so far. Is there any better solution to get the total number of records for the Pageable query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the CountQuery in the same annotation as the query itself. So

```
@Query(value = "select ...", countQuery = "select count..")
public List<EntityA > find....(@Param("") String value, Pageable pageable);
```

Also remove the "fetch" from the countQuery.

To get the total records, you can just reference the `page.getTotalElements()` to return the total number of records.

Comment: This is just another way to write query and count query in one method. I would say recommended way. I changed the return type to Page<EntityA> instead of List<EnitiyA> to call page.getTotalElements(). However, I have the same problem. I am now getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed".

Comment: The reason you need to put the count in the main query is for Spring JPA to know the total records. This is the reason you are getting the "Count query validation failed" error

Comment: Yes I understand that. However, the validation issue of my query was not resolved. Using count in a join query is still an issue for me.

Comment: Could you add your entity mapping as well?

Comment: public class EnitityA { @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "*", nullable = false)
  private Set<EntityB> listEntityB = new HashSet<>(); }.  EnityB does not have any field to show ManyToOne relationship. I am inserting EntityA and listEnityB in one save method. To do that, I had to arrange my mapping this way.

Comment: Remove the "fetch" in your count query. Just noticed that it is there in your original question.

Comment: Perfect!! Can you update your answer please and add some notes if possible about fetch? I will then accept it as the answer.